# PHP - How to add GET param to array and sort?

Tags: php, arrays, get, getparameter

Using PHP, I need to take all possible GET parameters from a URL, sort them into alphabetical order and then add all with values to an array. The parameters received will not always be the same.

As an example, if I receive the following; `https://example.com?PARAMA=123&PARAMB=&ANOTHERPARAM=example`

It needs to go into an array like this;

```
$dataArray = array (
     "ANOTHERPARAM"="example",
     "PARAMA"=123
)
```

Ensuring items that do not have a value is not entered into the array.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The URL of the page you are on or URL from a string somewhere? Did you try anything https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php?

Comment: Just try that: ```$dataArray = $_GET; ksort($dataArray);```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Added more relevant tags for easier searching.

Answer (score 0):

Use the global variable `$_GET`. It holds all the URL params passed to the page.  Then sort it using the `ksort` function, it sorts using the key.

```
 $dataArray = $_GET;
 $dataArray = array_filter($dataArray, 'strlen');
 ksort($dataArray);
```

For more details, check these:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: _Ensuring items that do not have a value is not entered into the array_